# Conditional Formulas in R

Tags: r, math

If I have a conditional formula such that:

time < theta :  y=x^2

time => theta : y=x

how do I use the as.formula function in R to build something like that? (I need to use the nls function on it too).

I've tried:

```
Data2 <-as.formula(y ~ (x<=theta)*x^2 + (x>theta)*x)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a meaningful description.

Comment: "Why is there no LaTeX here." - what do you mean?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I just wished to know whether the code that I'm using is correct or not, whether the mathematical function I described is coded as I  wrote?

Comment: @duffymo In the maths stackexchange I can use dollar signs to use LaTeX, makes it easier to show formula etc.

Comment: Are you trying to build a function that you can use to calculate on actual values?

Comment: @lmo yes that's right

Comment: Please provide more details. Is `theta` a fixed threshold or a parameter to be estimated?

Comment: @Roland it's a parameter to be estimated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use `nls` to fit a function that is not differentiable.

You can use `optimize` for this specific example:

```
#some example data
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(100, 0, 100)
y <- x
y[x <= 50] <- x[x <= 50]^2
y <- y + rnorm(100, sd = 0.01)     

fun <- function(x, theta) {
  #logical values are coerced to 0/1 automatically in calculations
  x * (x > theta) + x^2 * (x <= theta)
}    

SSE <- function(theta) {
  sum((y - fun(x, theta))^2) 
}

print(fit <- optimize(SSE, c(0, 100)))
#$minimum
#[1] 48.40996
#
#$objective
#[1] 0.008573424

plot(x, y)
lines(0:100, fun(0:100, fit$minimum))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably what you are looking for.

```
Myfunction <- function(time, x, theta) {
  if(time < theta) return(x^2)
  else return(x)
}
```

Note that a formula a very different object that is typically used to present a statistical model to a function. See `?function` and `?formula` for more details on these object types.

A vectorized version of this function:

```
Myfunction <- function(time, x, theta) {
  return((time < theta)*x^2 + (time >= theta)*x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could do that in R.

Comment: if theta was a parameter that needed estimation, could I use the nls function on it?

Comment: @MathsIsHard You may actually be looking for `nlm` not `nls`. I'm not too familiar with these functions, but `nlm` takes a function as its first argument.

Comment: This function is not vectorized and therefore useless for optimization.

Comment: @Roland I see what you mean.